# How to force Mithril to redraw without diffing? (integrating dragula in Mithril)

Tags: redraw, mithril.js, dragula

I am translating a JQuery-based app to Mithril. That app uses Dragula to allow drag/drop to reorder lists.

- Dragula reorders the `li` elements in the DOM.
- When the Drop event is fired, I sync the model and call `m.redraw()`.

However, the UI ends up in a mixed state:

```html
<li data-idx="0"> The Zero </li>
<li data-idx="1"> The One </li>
```

and after user dragging 1 before 0, it ends up as:

```html
<li data-idx="1"> The One</li>
<li data-idx="0"> The Zero</li>
```

Tried:

- `m.redraw()`, `m.redraw.sync()`, they correctly work but if ie. the LIs are moved by dragula, then the resulting HTML is in a mixed state.
- clearing `dom` in `vnode` with the hope it would be recreated.
- clearing `vmode.dom.textContent`
- Assign random keys and IDs to the widget container, and to the different LIs

... And nothing changes, either I get a blank widget or the values in "data-idx" are still wrong.

So my question is, in general, is it possible, and how, to use these kind of libraries that manipulate a mithril widget inner html, and then call m.redraw() so mithril re-renders the mess  ?

Background:

- Dragula is initialized in oncreate
- My widgets are mounted with route:

```js
"/videos": {
    onmatch: () => loginWall(true),
    render: v => m(layoutWidget, m(videosWidget, v.attrs))
},
```

Comment: ignore this question .... I was doing things in an anti-pattern way

Answer (score 1):

This is an older post but maybe you could provide more information about how the components are created in the `videosWidget`.  Mithril usually needs a key to distinguish between elements so that the current dom state is maintained as the model list changes as explained here: 
[keys](https://mithril.js.org/keys.html#keys).

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for the answer. Please ignore this question .... I was doing things in an anti-pattern way. Still today Mithril is my favourite engine :)